# A12 back not locking into Hasselblad 500 body

Tags: film, hasselblad

I just unloaded a roll of 120mm film and all of the sudden the magazine is not locking onto the body.

It appears that the two holes are not left completely open for the body to enter into them.

Is there any way of fixing it?

PS: I haven't loaded any film, but I don't think it would matter?

Comment: Is the magazine slide in? Is the indicator dot on the magazine white? Was the camera properly cocked before you removed the magazine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the camera was not properly cocked before the magazine was removed, you need to set the camera and magazine so that the indicator circles on the side of the camera and magazine are both white or both red.

[image]

The magazine slide must also be fully inserted into the side of the magazine.

[image]

These and other instructions can be found in the [Hasselblad 500C/M Manual](http://www.cameramanuals.org/hasselblad/hasselblad_500c_m-swc_m.pdf).